# Terraform doesnt realise Im already connected to Azure?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

Using an Azure Devops Pipeline, I have a cli task which connects to the azure subscription in my yaml file as below, i then run a script command after this task to run terraform plan but Terraform doesnt realise im already connected to Azure and gives a connection error? How can i get Terraform to use the existing connection in the preceding task? I dont want to pass any username and passwords in the terraform files

```
parameters:
  ServiceConnection:

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.ServiceConnection }}
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'echo test'

- script : terraform-plan
```

Comment: I would argue that Terraform is unaware of its surroundings. For example, how would Terraform know out of the box which OS you are using? Which CPU architecture for example? You have to download the right binary for your OS and use providers to communicate with the cloud provider. On the other hand, the provider code requires you to provide it with credentials so it can "talk" to the cloud provider of your choice. What would happen if you wanted to have a multi-cloud deployment? How would Terraform "know" in which cloud provider to create resources unless provided with credentials?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just run your `terraform plan` command **within** the `AzureCLI` step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your YAML sample, you are using Azure CLI task to connect azure subscription and save credentials.

This credential is only valid in Azure Cli task.

After the Azure Cli task is executed, `az account clear` command will be run to clear the credentials, so the credentials cannot be used by the next task.

Refer to the log of Azure CLI task:

[image]

To solve this issue, you can use script or bash task to execute the az login command. Then the credentials will be pass to next tasks.

For example:

```
steps:
…
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: xx
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_ID]$servicePrincipalId" 
     
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET]$servicePrincipalKey"
    
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_TENANT_ID]$tenantId"
    addSpnToEnvironment: true

- bash: |
   az login --service-principal --username $(ARM_CLIENT_ID) --password $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)  --tenant $(ARM_TENANT_ID)

  displayName: 'Bash Script'

- script : terraform-plan
```

You can set `addSpnToEnvironment: true` in Azure CLI task and then the credentials of the service connection can be used in next task to run az login.