# AZ CLI Task not logging in

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am somewhat new to AZURE Pipelines. Trying to run a simple bash script by itself that will create a resource group, storage account and container. I am being prompted by the Bash@3 task to run az login. Did some research and found out I likely need to add the AzureCLI@2 task as well, which I did. Still prompts me to run az login using a browser and device code. I did setup a service connection in ADO.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Prepare Credentials'
  inputs:
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
      azureSubscription: 'ADO'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      scriptType: 'bash'
      inlineScript: |
        az --version
        az login
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/remotestate.sh'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/'
    failOnStderr: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you only run az login command, it will request to use device code and manually sign in.

When you use the Azure CLI task, it will automatically execute the az login command based on your service connection. You don't need to add extra az login command.

So you can directly define the file path in Azure CLI task to run the bash script.

For example:

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/remotestate.sh'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ADO
    scriptType: bash
    scriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/remotestate.sh'
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
```

Refer to the doc about [Azure CLI Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops).

On the other hand, if you need to run the bash file in next bash tasks. You can use Azure CLI task to export the login information and then use bash task to execute the az login command. Then the credentials will be pass to next tasks.

For example:

```
steps:

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: xx
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_ID]$servicePrincipalId" 

     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET]$servicePrincipalKey"

     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_TENANT_ID]$tenantId"
    addSpnToEnvironment: true

- bash: |
   az login --service-principal --username $(ARM_CLIENT_ID) --password $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)  --tenant $(ARM_TENANT_ID)'

  displayName: 'Bash Script'

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/remotestate.sh'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/'
    failOnStderr: true
```

Refer to this ticket: [Terraform doesnt realise Im already connected to Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72982344/terraform-doesnt-realise-im-already-connected-to-azure/72989842#72989842)

Comment: I think the key piece for me here is that I need to pass the credentials to the next task. Doesn't make sense if the previous command logs in - isn't it running in the same session?

Comment: @Vegas588 When you  Azure CLI task run az login command , it will run the command `az account clear` to clear the credentials at the end of the azure cli task.  To let the credentials to work in the next tasks, you can follow the method 2. In this case, it will use the credentials of the service connection and then if you run the az login in bash task instead of azure cli task, it can work in the whole agent job instead of the same session

Comment: Not sure I fully understand that. I am having a different error now. When I run the pipeline, it seems to be using a different service principal ID (one that is old). It is not using the new Service Connection I created. I have deleted the pipeline and recreated it, but it seems to be stuck using some old ID.

Comment: You can update the service connection name in the Azure CLI task: `azureSubscription: xx`. And check if it can work. Or you can update the error to question and I can try to help you with it

Comment: I's not working. I will post a new question.

Comment: Working fully now. Thank you.