# Azure Pipelines Authentication Failure

Tags: azure-pipelines

This is a follow-up question to a previous [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74283623/az-cli-task-not-logging-in/74285635?noredirect=1#comment131156777_74285635).

I created a new Azure DevOps Service Connection. I have verified it. Application ID starts with "b030..."

When I run the pipeline and it gets to the bash task, authentication fails and it mentions a completely different ID, starting with "5fb6..."

ERROR: (AuthorizationFailed) The client 5fb6... does not have authorization to perform...

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: 'Azure CLI'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'ADO'
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_ID]$servicePrincipalId" 
  
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET]$servicePrincipalKey"
  
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_TENANT_ID]$tenantId"
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
  
  - bash: |
      az login --service-principal --username $(ARM_CLIENT_ID) --password $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)  --tenant $(ARM_TENANT_ID)
  
    displayName: 'Bash Script'
  
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/remotestate.sh'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/'
      failOnStderr: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error information you described : (AuthorizationFailed) The client 5fb6... does not have authorization to perform..., it means that your application has no access to resources
in your subscription. You must assign a role to your application. Refer to the doc : [Azure AD app in the portal](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Factive-directory%2Fdevelop%2Fhowto-create-service-principal-portal%23option-2-create-a-new-application-secret&data=05%7C01%7Cv-douxu%40microsoft.com%7C072ad2b7409f4a173ca608dabe380cf4%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C638031445285326193%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=g94CKbEKCv6xDF6FmIyMZyKjT3HQjkPOSt5ItgEmHs8%3D&reserved=0)

1 make sure the Object ID of your registered app in Enterprise applications and the Object ID of app you want to assign a role in your subscription is the same.(Application ID maps to Object ID )
[image: Object ID]
2 assign a role to the application
[image: assign a role to the application]

run the YAML pipeline after assigning an appropriate role, you can  see Authentication successful in below
[image: pipeline]

Comment: I created a new service principle manually in Azure and then added that as a new service connection in ADO. The issue has been solved.